# Is it possible to remove the option to minimize a window?

Tags: windows-10

I have started using certain time tracking software to get a better idea of where I spend my time. I want to keep the software's window always on top of all other windows, but sometimes I accidentally minimize the window. Is it possible to remove the option to minimize the window?

Comment: The ability to minimize an application is entirely left up to the author of the application on Windows.

Comment: Which software are you using? Toggl?

Comment: If you change `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` for `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` will remove the entire titlebar. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/this-uses-inbuilt-compilers-in-windows.html

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, I am using Toggl

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will use the following keys
to modify the currently active window:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> : remove minimize and maximize buttons, set the window to be always on top, start a timer to
  test if it's minimized and then restore it
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> : undo the above

Here is the script:

```
winid := 0

^F11::
  WinSet, Style, -0x30000, A    ; remove minimize and maximize buttons
  Winset, Alwaysontop, On, A    ; set it on top of all other windows
  WinGet, winid, ID, A          ; keep the ID of the active window
  SetTimer, RestoreWindow, 500  ; run RestoreWindow subroutine every half a second
  return

^F12::
  WinSet, Style, +0x30000, A    ; add minimize and maximize buttons
  SetTimer, RestoreWindow, Off  ; stop RestoreWindow from looping
  winid := 0
  Winset, Alwaysontop, Off, A   ; undo on top
  return
  
RestoreWindow:
  WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_id winid
  If MinMax = -1                ; if window is minimized
    WinRestore, ahk_id winid
  return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Simply removing the button does not make it impossible to minimize the window tho.

Comment: @Gantendo: Right, I extended my answer.

Comment: I would probably check if the window is minimized (in a loop) and then restore it if that is the case. I think that would be more efficient than removing the min/max buttons because I can minimize windows without ever using those buttons.

Comment: @Gantendo: I think the current script answers all criticism.

Comment: Perfectissimo! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because the minimize button is shown and developed by the author of the app. But you can switch to tablet mode so that you can disable window minimizing, behaving like a tablet. It's even better if your device has touch capabilities.

## How to enable?

Go to Start -> Settings -> System -> Tablet -> Additional* Then toggle "Tablet Mode".

## What happens?

Your device starts behaving like a tablet. Minimize option is gone.

## Other Effects

The restore and close button is gone too!

Comment: That's not true : The program only specifies if it wants them or not, the rest is done by Windows.